# mod rewrite with multiple parameters on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have problems with setting mod rewrite on one of my wordpress websites below is htaccess:

```
# BEGIN s2Member GZIP exclusions
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1
    RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
</IfModule>
# END s2Member GZIP exclusions

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^book/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ book/?bookid=$1&bookt=$2
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Below line doesnt seem to work

```
RewriteRule ^book/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ book/?bookid=$1&bookt=$2
```

I want links www.example.com/book/1/tittle show content from www.example.com/book/?bookid=1&bookt=tittle

Edit:
This might help:
www.example.com/book/1/test shows "page not found" while www.example.com/book/1/ shows page - but obviously without second variable

Comment: Is `www.example.com/book/?bookid=1&bookt=tittle` a WP URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `L` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^book/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ book/?bookid=$1&bookt=$2 [L]
```

Comment: www.example.com/book/1/test still shows "page not found" while www.example.com/book/1/ shows page - but obviously without second variable